# Can a hacker install known-vulnerable software on a machine in order to control the PC and elude antivirus?

Tags: attacks, antivirus, known-vulnerabilities

I recently discovered that on one of my PCs the SolarWinds software was installed.
I didn't install this software on my machine.

I also saw that SolarWinds was cracked by Russian hackers and also companies like Microsoft have a lot of data leaks.

Is it possible that I'm a victim of a hacker attack?

And what I can do now in order to secure myself?

Comment: If an attacker had the admin privileges necessary to install Solarwinds on your computer, they wouldn't need Solarwinds as a path to attacking your computer.

Comment: It's like saying can a thief break into my house to open a window so they can break into my house.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible to install weak software in order to get more access to a machine. This is a known approach.

However, if you have access to install something, you tend to have enough access already. SolarWinds provided a backdoor, and if you can install SolarWinds, then you can simply install a backdoor.

If the software gave you *more* access than you might have (like system-level access) then it becomes a viable approach. But that's not the case with SolarWinds.